# How to add Custom Property to System.Managment Object using WMI, C# in ASP.Net Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, iis-6, wmi

AA,

I want to add a custom property to a WMi Object's Propert Collection. So that whenever i retrieve the properties of that object, i get the custom added property as well. Specifically speaking lets see the following code.

```
foreach (ManagementObject WebSite in WebSitesCollection)
        {
            if (WebSite.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString().Contains(appPoolName))
            {
                foreach (PropertyData propertyData in WebSite.Properties)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(propertyData.Name + "  " + propertyData.Value + "<br/>");
                        if (propertyData.Name.Equals("Enable32BitAppOnWin64"))
                        {
                            AppPoolx.SetPropertyValue("Enable32BitAppOnWin64", true);
                            AppPoolx.Put(); return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                         AppPoolx.Properties.Add("Enable32BitAppOnWin64", true);
                          AppPoolx.Put(); return true;
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex1)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Error Ocurred while Setting Property: " + ex1.Message + "<br />");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

**But the   `AppPoolx.Properties.Add("Enable32BitAppOnWin64", true);` returns error**

**Operation is not valid due to current state of the object.**

I was wondering whether it was even possible to add a custom property to the WMi object. If what is this Add() function for?

In any case, what is the correct procedure of add a "Custom Property to a WMI Object."

Please do not suggest that i may store in DB.

Regards

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WMI Objects are basically com objects, much like a C# object those objects are populated by the code at the other end.

For you to add this custom property you would have to have the functionality in the code at the other end to store the object data for your custom property.

The add property method you're calling is not valid for all (pretty much most) com objects that are returned by WMI API's this is likely your problem, i understand that this is something to do with how the objects from WMI calls are marshalled from the com component in which they are called from.

So in short:
This is not likely possible.

A more correct approach would be to determine the actual type of the object you are working with and set a property value on a property that is writable for the object then push that back to the WMI API.